# How to calculate sum of each group last row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

#### vehicle_assignment_history

```
id    companyAccountId          date           totalVan     totalBike
1            4           2021-11-11 00:00:00     2             0
2            4           2021-11-11 00:00:00     3             0
3            4           2021-11-11 00:00:00     1             0        
4            8           2021-11-11 00:00:00     1             0
5            8           2021-11-12 00:00:00     2             0        
6            9           2021-11-13 00:00:00     0             2
7            9           2021-11-14 00:00:00     0             1
```

I want to calculate sum of each group last row of `companyAccountId`.also the date bewteen a range.

for example:-
`2021-11-11 -> 2021-11-13`

```
   totalVan              totalBike
1 + 2 + 0 = 3           0 + 0 + 2 = 2
```

`2021-11-11 -> 2021-11-14`

```
   totalVan              totalBike
1 + 2 + 0 = 3           0 + 0 + 1 = 1
```

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Your example up here seems a bit irrelevant when compared with the data of vehicle assignment history you have provided

Comment: @ysth '5.7.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'

Comment: is the only way to tell what's latest comparing `id`?  or `date` and `id`?

Comment: @ysth yes id only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to take the max (for each companyAccountId) of a complex string that joins the id and the field you want to find for the highest id, then extract the field you want from the end and convert it back to a number (all in a subquery, so you can sum all the resulting values)

```
select sum(latestTotalVan) as totalVan, sum(latestTotalBike) as totalBike
from (
    select
        cast(substring(max(concat(lpad(id,11,'0'),totalVan)) from 12) as unsigned) latestTotalVan,
        cast(substring(max(concat(lpad(id,11,'0'),totalBike)) from 12) as unsigned) latestTotalBike
    from vehicle_assignment_history
    where date between '2021-11-11 00:00:00' and '2021-11-14 00:00:00'
    group by companyAccountId
) latest_values
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e18acc772ddac58e3f85108cdfc781c5)

mysql 8 adds window functions that make this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: you can thank me best by making sure you understand how it works so you can do it yourself next time something like this comes up :)   please do ask if anything is unclear

Comment: sure, i will @ysth

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
companyAccountId,
sum(totalVan) AS [Total Vans],
sum(totalBike) AS [Total Bike],
FROM vehicle_assignment_history
GROUP BY companyAccountId
HAVING '2021-11-11' < date AND date < '2021-11-13'

Comment: its not working return empty data.